# How to create an empty, coloured CGImage canvas in Swift

Tags: swift, image, core-graphics

I want to draw some lines over an empty CGImage black canvas. Should be something trivial creating a blank CGImage of an specific size but I'm not able. I've tried to extend CGImage init? calling self.init(width:height:...bitmapInfo:provider:...) with the required information but I don't know enough about CGBitmapInfo and CGDataProvider.

Any help or guidance on how to create this empty canvas? Any other approach not using UIKit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't draw on a `CGImage`, you draw on a `CGContext`.  What you want to do is create a bitmap context, draw into the bitmap context, then create an image from the context bitmap buffer.  Here is a sample that I typed up in a Playground.

import UIKit

```
// CGContexts like rowbytes that are multiples of 16.
func goodBytesPerRow(_ width: Int) -> Int {
    return (((width * 4) + 15) / 16) * 16
}

func drawMyImage() -> CGImage? {
    let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: 200, height: 200)
    let intWidth = Int(ceil(bounds.width))
    let intHeight = Int(ceil(bounds.height))
    let bitmapContext = CGContext(data: nil,
                                  width: intWidth, height: intHeight,
                                  bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                  bytesPerRow: goodBytesPerRow(intWidth),
                                  space: CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!,
                                  bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)

    if let cgContext = bitmapContext {
        cgContext.saveGState()
        cgContext.setFillColor(gray: 0, alpha: 1.0)
        cgContext.fill(bounds)

        /* ... do other drawing here ... */

        cgContext.restoreGState()

        return cgContext.makeImage()
    }

    return nil
}

let image = drawMyImage()
```

This is drawing using 32 bit ARGB values.
Core Graphics likes it best when its row bytes is a mutiple of 16 (or at least it did in 2006 when I wrote a Quartz 2D book).  So `goodBytesPerRow` calculates, for 32-bit ARGB pixels, a rowBytes that is a multiple of 16 for a given width.

The "bitmapInfo" is a combination of constants and determines more specifics of the pixel format `CGImageAlphaInfo` and `CGBitmapInfo`.  In this case we're saying we want the alpha channel to be first (so ARGB instead of RGBA) and we want to use pixels where the color channels are premultiplied by the alpha values.

Once you have the bitmap context you can draw what you like.  You said you wanted to draw some lines on a black background - so this just gives you the black background and leaves the lines as an exercise for the reader.

At the very end you get a `CGImage` from the context using `makeImage`.  If you wanted a `UIImage`, you could construct one with `UIImage(cgImage:)`

P.S.  You would use `CGImageProvider` if you wanted to construct an image from a raw chunk of memory, or by streaming data out of a file, or some other source.  It basically tells the system how to get the image data.

In this case, when we create the bitmap context, we pass in "nil" as the data which asks the OS to allocate the frame buffer for the image for us.

Comment: Scott,  I would like to do recursive rendering using CGContext.   This is desirable when rendering a very large array of data, and only a small portion of it needs to be updated during each View update.  How would I modify your answer if I wanted to make repeated calls to the drawMyImage() func where each call updates (i.e., writes on top of) the previously generated CGImage (instead of creating a brand new CGImage)?  Is this possible?

Comment: @KeithB The image data is immutable.  To use this technique you would keep the context and draw on it each time, but create a new CGImage with each rendering.  However, depending on what you are trying to do, you may want to do your drawing into a CGLayer instead of into a context/image.

Comment: Scott,  Could I ask you to modify your code above by adding code for:  "... do other drawing here ...".  The Core Graphics syntax is not obvious how to specify and stroke individual pixels for drawing a line.

Comment: @KeithB Core Graphics is not a pixel oriented drawing library.  You don't "stroke individual pixels".  Drawing is done in a resolution independent drawing space and then mapped to a drawing surface (like the image).  Perhaps create a question about the effect you are trying to achieve?